# How can I run a SQL query iteratively for every row in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @AccString varchar(max)
SET @AccString=''


SELECT @Acctring=@AccString + description + '  [   ]    ' 
FROM tl_sb_accessoryInventory ai
JOIN tl_sb_accessory a on a.accessoryID = ai.accessoryID
WHERE userID=6 

SELECT userID, serviceTag, model, @AccString AS ACCESSORIES FROM tl_sb_oldLaptop ol
JOIN tl_sb_laptopType lt ON ol.laptopTypeID = lt.laptopTypeID
WHERE userID=6
```

which outputs this:

[image]

What I want to be able to do is run this for every userID in a table tl_sb_user.

The statement to get the userIDs is:

```
Select userID from tl_sb_user
```

How can I get this to output a row as above for each user?

Comment: Use corelation subquery.

Comment: Why are you using SQL to construct what looks like a paper form? There are lots of tools out there for building interesting layouts and performing complex string processing. SQL isn't one of those tools.

Comment: True - but this is for a one-hit quick and dirty mail-merge. Didn't want to spend the time learning to use a new tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do a string concatenation subquery.  In SQL Server, you need to do the string concatenation using a correlated subquery with `for xml path`.  Arcane, but it generally works.

The results is something like this:

```
SELECT userID, serviceTag, model, @AccString AS ACCESSORIES,
       stuff((select  '  [   ]    ' + description
              from tl_sb_accessoryInventory ai join
                   tl_sb_accessory a
                   on a.accessoryID = ai.accessoryID
              where a.userId = ol.UserId
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 11, '') as accessories
FROM tl_sb_oldLaptop ol JOIN
     tl_sb_laptopType lt
     ON ol.laptopTypeID = lt.laptopTypeID;
```

You don't have table aliases identifying where the columns come from, so I am just guessing that `a.userId = ol.UserId` references the right tables.

Also, this substitutes certain characters with html forms.  Notably `'<'` and `'>'` turn into things like `'&lt;'` and `'&gt;'`.  When I encounter this problem, I use `replace()` to replace the values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave out the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: That won't work because it will add every item to every user.